# How do I make a multi panel plot like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I have tried using gridspec, everything looks fine but mi main plot doesn't fill all the space.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/frHEN.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA1Sg.png
This is my code:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from FUNCION import *
from FUNCIONAVG import *

f = h5py.File('Datos1', 'r')

list(f.keys())

print(f.keys());

data=f['default'];

data=np.array(data)

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5, 5))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(8, 8)
gs.update(wspace=0, hspace=0)

xtr_subplot = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:6, 0:2])
base = plt.gca().transData
rot = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(90)
line = plt.plot(sum, transform=rot + base)
plt.ylabel("Y Label")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])

xtr_subplot = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:6, 2:6])
plt.imshow(data, aspect=(6/4))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])

xtr_subplot = fig.add_subplot(gs[6:8, 2:6])
plt.plot(avg)

plt.savefig("multipanel.png")


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `aspect` argument of [`plt.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib import transforms

data = np.random.randn(100).reshape(10, 10)
avg = np.random.randn(10)
total = np.random.randn(10)

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5, 5))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(8, 8)
gs.update(wspace=0, hspace=0)

xtr_subplot = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:6, 0:2])
base = plt.gca().transData
rot = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(90)
line = plt.plot(total, transform=rot + base)
plt.ylabel("Y Label")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])

xtr_subplot = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:6, 2:6])
plt.imshow(data, aspect=(6 / 4))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])

xtr_subplot = fig.add_subplot(gs[6:8, 2:6])
plt.plot(avg)

plt.savefig("multipanel.png")
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried It and It doesn't work. the variable data is a 2x2 array, I don't know if that's the problem. This is how I opened my file of data:     f= h5py.File('Datos1', 'r')

list(f.keys())

print(f.keys());

data=f['default'];

data=np.array(data)

Comment: @JavierGómez you tried what, and what didn't work? you have to set the aspect parameter of plt.imshow, i.e., `plt.imshow(data, aspect=(6 / 4))`

Comment: I have tried that exact thing, I included the exact line you gave me plt.imshow(data, aspect=(6 / 4)) and I doesn't change anything. Do you have another Idea? I can send you my whole code if you want to try It.

Comment: @JavierGómez it would be better that you emend your question to include as much of the code as is necessary to reproduce your failed attempt (a minimum working example).

Comment: Ok, I'm doing It. Check the question

Comment: For the varibles sum and avg you can use random numbers

Comment: I just fixed It!! Just set the aspect as 'auto' and It works. Thank you very much buddy!!!!